# Is the pressure gradient perpendicular to the flow direction or along the flow direction?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow

I know that the pressure gradient is the pressure difference per unit length, but I'm not sure what direction it is.

Answer (score 2):

In viscous flow, the pressure gradient *due to flow* is parallel to the flow, pointing in the opposite direction. This is because the gradient points in the direction of increase, but pressure decreases in the flow direction.

You can, however, have pressure gradients in other directions due to external forces like gravity.

Comment: "...but pressure decreases in the flow direction. " If you are referring to the static pressure, it can either increase or decrease in the flow direction, depending on the shape of the object & details of the flow. But perhaps you are referring to the total pressure, since viscous dissipation causes a continual decrease in the flow direction.